# Store and retrieve Excel PageSetup

Tags: excel, vba, page-setup

I'm programming an Excel VBA macro to automate a print task. What I want to do is to store the PageSetup object of a workbook, do my things, and then restore the initial parameters. I tried this :

```
Sub test()

Dim TempPageSetup As PageSetup

    Set TempPageSetup = ActiveSheet.PageSetup

    'Modify the ActiveSheet.PageSetup 
    'Print the worksheet

    Set ActiveSheet.PageSetup = TempPageSetup


End Sub
```

But I get "Object variable or With block variable not set" error when I try to put back the initial pagesetup object. Is a worksheet pagesetup object readonly?

I also tried to put it back property by property in a With activeSheet.PageSetup statement. That seems to work but at some point I got an "Automation error" and Excel just shut down. I run the code step by step and it does not always happen on the same property. Any explanation? I'm still investigating what is going on.

Comment: You can't update the entire object, there are read only properties like `Application` that exist.  You'll need to pick out specific properties that you want to update, so basically, whatever you change, that's what needs to be set back.

Comment: Thanks... and I also realised that I only assigned a new pointer toward the same object. So every thing I change is also change in the tempPageSetup object. Need to rethink my strategy.

Comment: It's a long way around but what if you saved a temp version of the workbook, open it up, make your changes to page setup, print and then close and delete the file?  Something like that.